# how to map properties of a member object of an entity to the table field in EF Code First

Tags: entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first, poco, entity-framework-4.3

i m using EF Code First, and want to map an Entity class Person to entity table personTable as follows,

i have a an Entity Class

```
public class Person
{
    public Guid Id
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string Email
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public int Property
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public Name Name
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

and a class for type of Property Name

```
public class Name
{
    public string FirstName
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string FullName
    {
        get
        {
            return string.Format("{0} {1} {2}", FirstName, MiddleName, LastName);
        }
    }

    public string LastName
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string MiddleName
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

i want to map person class to person table as follows

```
Person.Id => personTable.ID
Person.Name.FirstName ->personTable.FirstName
Person.Name.MiddleName => personTable.MiddleName
Person.Name.LastName => personTable.LastName
and so on....
```

where `Person.Name` is an object of type `Name Class`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Name` is a complex type and you must EF tell this, otherwise it will consider `Name` as an entity and `Person.Name` as a navigation property. Mapping with Fluent API:

```
modelBuilder.ComplexType<Name>();

modelBuilder.Entity<Person>()
    .Property(p => p.Name.FirstName)
    .HasColumnName("FirstName");

modelBuilder.Entity<Person>()
    .Property(p => p.Name.MiddleName)
    .HasColumnName("MiddleName");

modelBuilder.Entity<Person>()
    .Property(p => p.Name.LastName)
    .HasColumnName("LastName");
```